# Jquery Showing hidden text after .click() is called. Might be issue with Jquery not being installed correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this might be a repeat question but I still need help. I am creating a website that when a button is clicked on, the text will appear. I have it hidden in a div using display: none on a class. When I'm testing the site ill click the button and nothing happens. There are no errors on the console so I'm assuming its an issue with Jquery not being installed correctly (I did use the npm install jquery).

```js
$(function(){
   $(".button").click(function(){
      $(".projectTextInfo").toggleClass(".show"); 
   });
});
```

```css
.projectTextInfo {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row justify-content-start">
    <div class = "mr-4 mb-5 monxProject  col-md-6 col-sm-6"> 
        <div class = "caption">
        <h4 class="project-text"> Ludem Dare </h4>
    </div>
    <div class = "thumbnail">
        <img class="projectIcon" src = "http://monxcleyr.net/images/mainsite/LDsmall.png">
        <button class="button">Test</button>
        <div class="projectTextInfo">
            <p>Howdy</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`toggleClass(".show")` is wrong , it is `toggleClass("show")`. Try it:

```js
$(function(){
   $(".button").click(function(){
      $(".projectTextInfo").toggleClass("show"); 
   });
});
```

```css
.projectTextInfo {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row justify-content-start">
    <div class = "mr-4 mb-5 monxProject  col-md-6 col-sm-6"> 
        <div class = "caption">
        <h4 class="project-text"> Ludem Dare </h4>
    </div>
    <div class = "thumbnail">
        <img class="projectIcon" src = "http://monxcleyr.net/images/mainsite/LDsmall.png">
        <button class="button">Test</button>
        <div class="projectTextInfo">
            <p>Howdy</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```